# statsmodels==0.13.2 downloading infinitely

Tags: python, statsmodels

Unable to install, as the model statsmodels==0.13.2 is downloading infinitely in google colab.

```
pip install statsmodels==0.13.2
Collecting statsmodels>=0.12.2
  Using cached statsmodels-0.13.2.tar.gz (17.9 MB)
```

Comment: Can you update your answer with a more verbose output? `pip install --verbose statsmodels==0.13.2`

Comment: Likely fixed now that wheels for 0.13.2 are on PyPI.

Comment: @KevinS Now working fine with same command. Is this an intermittent issue ?

Comment: The well was posted last night. Collab was attempting to build from source which can be very slow.